# Organizing media files (pdf) and searching based on the folders created

Tags: search, directory, filesystem, pdf, search-engines

I am attempting to find a way to search through sorted PDF files inside the media section of WP. My goal is to be able to set up different search engines within my site that pull from specified folders. At the moment I am using CatFolders to do the organization and SearchWP for the search functionality. I am considering a different search plugin to accomplish this.

My problem lies in that the CatFolders folder structure does not appear anywhere else on my Wordpress, besides in the media section. I would like to be able to access those folders and attach them to a specific search bar but so far I have not found how to accomplish this.

Any constructive information is appreciated.